# Javascript screen resolution reset on load

Tags: javascript, resize, resolution

I am using a javascript function to reset the style of 3 DIVs based on the user screen resolution using the onload event.

```
if(screen.width > 1024 && screen.width < 1300){
 document.getElementById('wrapper').style.width = '1250px';
 document.getElementById('innerwrapper').style.width = '1250px';
 var elms = getElementsByClassName("colmask", "div")[0].style.width = '1250px';
}
if(screen.width > 1300 && screen.width < 1500){
 document.getElementById('wrapper').style.width = '1350px';
 document.getElementById('innerwrapper').style.width = '1350px';
 var elms = getElementsByClassName("colmask", "div")[0].style.width = '1350px';
} 
if(screen.width > 1500){
 document.getElementById('wrapper').style.width = '1580px';
 document.getElementById('innerwrapper').style.width = '1580px';
 var elms = getElementsByClassName("colmask", "div")[0].style.width = '1580px';
}
```

The problem is every time the user navigates to a new page the screen resizes it self after loading the page. Is there a way to avoid having to resize the pages all the time ?

Comment: If you'll forgive me for being blunt and judgmental, this is a terrible idea. Do not use fixed-width layouts, particularly ones tied to pixel values. (There is a valid argument to be made for displaying large amounts of prose in columns whose width is fixed based on the font size in order to protect the user from themselves and target a fixed line length.) Make a dynamic layout that works for screens and devices with varying resolution and dpi.

Comment: I agree, just because their resolution supports the page width doesn't mean they have their browser full screened.  Users will get aggrivated having to make their browser large enough to fit the content simply based on their *screen* resolution.

Comment: If you insist on doing this, then send the width/height back to the server via AJAX or a form and have the client output the css with the size values in place already. That should force the page to render at the proper size automatically without having to "pop" into place.

Comment: @Shahid - where is this code located in your HTML?

Comment: @Phrogz, Soviut: I agree with you totally. however this particular client is insisting on having exactly that even though i have explained.

Comment: @Julian: The code is in an external .js file as a function called by javascript window.onload in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above and to make it dynamic based on the size of the browser is pretty easy if you decide to use Jquery

all you have to do is `var wcontent=$(window).width();`
and

```
$("#wrapper").width(wcontent);
```

and so on

which you can place on the `$(document).ready(function () {}`

Comment: I am not using jquery but is this not equivalent to what i am already doing?

Comment: I wrote that yesterday before all the other comments about the fixed div sizes and also with this way it doesnt resize when the user navitages to a new page.  Its obviously the same just managed a bit better